# Android - Popup window creation and styling

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a popup window which has several `RelativeLayout`, several `TextView` and a single `Button`.

Here's the popup window :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_Wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/popupPhoneMessage"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_functionalities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to display it on an `Activity`? Tried using `LayoutInflater` but got an error saying it found `View` instead..

Code :

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_MainLayout);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout popupLayoutInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_handphone, mainLayout);

//This part here said it needs android.widget.RelativeLayout, but found android.view.View

        popupLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.popup_handphone);
```

[image: Popup Image]

Here's the popup I wanted. The greyed one is the popup containing two `TextViews` and one `Button`

Managed to create a popup using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk). But there's a black background around the popup window Like this

[image: Black popup]

Here's an updated code for `onclick` on `TextView`

```
View.OnClickListener phoneReinputHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupStepTwoActivity.this, PopupHandphone.class);
            backDim = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bac_dim_layout);
            //backDim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startActivity(intent);

    };
```

How to remove the black thingy?

Comment: your code and logcat is a must for one to answer..

Comment: Yup added it, forgot to add it

Comment: have you tried making the parent relativelayout background as transparent?

Comment: Yup tried that and it seems that is not the relative background which causes that.. Could it be the theme? I'm working on using `PopupWindow` now though, working on dismissing it by touching outside the window

Comment: it might be because of them, i have never worked on popupwindow so not quite sure, but the design that you provided can be easily created using dialog

Comment: Isn't dialog more like.. An alert box which has `positive`, `neutral`, and `negative` `Button`?

Answer (score 0):

see this and do modifications as per your needs

```
public void showDialog()
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material);/*choose your theme*/
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));/*choose your style*/
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);/*to remove title*/
         dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); //Optional
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_dash_wish);/*enter your xml layout name*/
    //Any other code you want in your constructor

    TextView popup_handphone_text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_text);
    EditText popup_handphone_phoneNumber = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_phoneNumber);

    EditText popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_id);
    button .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Umm sorry is this for `Dialog`? I need `PopupWindow`.. Can `AlertDialog` be used like `PopupWindow`?

Comment: it can be used as popup window as well, can you post a pictorial representation of what you actually want to achieve? that will certainly help us visualize your requirements